# Recortar múltiples archivos ráster a partir de coordenadas locales

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando con múltiples imágenes MODIS(una sola banda, extraída previamente) en R. Me gustaría encontrar la manera de, en este caso, extraer el píxel x = 1 e y = 1 de todas ellas e introducirlos en un raster stack para después aplicarles otras operaciones.
He intentado diferentes cosas pero no doy con la tecla.
Por ejemplo, he estado probando cosas de este estilo.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

setwd("/Users/guillermorodriguezlopez/Desktop/ndsi_modis") #Directorio

# Carga de imagenes
images <- list.files(path=getwd(),
                     pattern="*.tif$|*.TIF$")
imagestack <- stack(images) #Stack con los archivos raster. 

for (i in seq_along(imagestack)) {
  r = stack(crop(imagestack, extent(imagestack, 1,1,1,1)))
  }
```

Si a alguien tiene alguna idea, será bienvenida!
Gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo!!

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres recortar un raster en R lo mejor es usar el comando `crop` de la librería `raster`, que se puede aplicar directamente sobre tu stack. Para usar este comando debemos introducir la extensión a la que queremos que se haga el recorte. Por lo tanto, hay que obtener la extensión previamente.

La extensión podemos obtenerla a partir del stack.

```
# obtenemos la extensión original
extension<-extent(imagestack)
```

El objeto `extension` contiene en este orden, X mínimo, X máximo, Y mínimo e Y máximo. A partir de él podemos obtener la extensión del píxel 1,1. Entiendo que este píxel es el de la esquina superior izquierda, por lo tanto su extensión viene dada por la ymax y xmin, a los que les restamos y sumamos la resolución de la imagen.

```
# creamos la extensión del píxel 1 a partir de la extensión total
ext1<-extension
resolucion<-10 # en metros

# la nueva x maxima es la x mínima más la resolución
ext1[2]<-ext1[1]+resolucion 

# la nueva y mínima es la y máxima menos la resolución
ext1[3]<-ext1[4]-resolucion
```

Una vez tenemos la extensión, ya podemos recortar

```
# recortamos usando crop
recorte<-crop(imagestack, ext1)
```

Comment: Creo que puede funcionar!! Muchísmas gracias, HMSP! Que tengas buen día!

Comment: Si te funciona, por favor acepta la respuesta (mira aquí como hacerlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Gracias